# Creating a popup CMenu without a checkbox

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, windows-forms-designer, cmenu

I am creating a CMenu in Visual Studio 2010, MFC.  I have a working CMenu that appears when a user right-clicks on a dialog.  I can't seem to find a way to create menu selection **without** a spot for a checkbox.  In  Visual Studio's designer, my menu looks like this:

[image: Checkbox]

[image]

I wish to remove the area for a checkmark. In my application, my menu looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to remove this small box, left of "Change Option"?

**Update:** Not sure this will help, but this is my code to create the CMenu:

```
CMenu menu;
VERIFY(menu.LoadMenu(IDR_MENU1));
CMenu* pPopup = menu.GetSubMenu(0);
ASSERT(pPopup != NULL);
CWnd* pWndPopupOwner = this;
while (pWndPopupOwner->GetStyle() & WS_CHILD)
            pWndPopupOwner = pWndPopupOwner->GetParent();
pPopup->TrackPopupMenu(TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, screenPoint.x, screenPoint.y,
            pWndPopupOwner);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use an owner-draw menu for this.  Popup menus always (by default) have space allocated for checkmark bitmaps.  Going owner-draw will allow you to use `CMenu::MeasureItem()` and `CMenu::DrawItem()` to customize the size and drawing behavior of the menu object to your needs.